# How to bulk upload NFTs to an existing collection?

Tags: remix, nft

I'm planning to create a new collection contains 10000 NFTs using Remix.ethereum with smart contract. I would like to upload 1000 NFTs for the first time, then upload another 1000 NFTs a month later to the same collection.

Can I bulk upload NFTs to an existing collection? If so, how?

Do I have to pay more fees this way? How much would that be for the total of 10K NFTs?

Comment: Have you found the solution? As far as I tested, the new bulk upload created a new collection. MyColl -> MyColl V2; Also, I found this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/112958/is-it-possible-to-take-an-existing-erc-1155-collection-on-open-sea-and-include
Which seems it is not possible.