# Is it possible to take an existing ERC-1155 collection on Open Sea, and include it in a newly deployed ERC-1155 contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-721, erc-1155, opensea

I am more familiar with ERC-721 and related operations, so wanted to ask this question.

I am working with someone who has an existing collection that was created via Open Sea and is currently an ERC-1155 token.

Is it possible to create a new ERC-1155 contract to deploy (for minting new phases of the project), and also include the original ERC-1155 tokens as a part of this project?

I'm thinking this might require either an airdrop or users to mint their existing ERC-1155 tokens again on this contract, but heard from someone at Open Sea that "its possible to transfer the old collection to the new collection".

In searching for resources on this topic, haven't found anything definitive yet to clarify this for me. Does anyone have any insight or good docs to read on this?

I know that an ERC-721 migration is not possible and would require re-minting/burning to complete. Just curious if there are other options available to ERC-1155.

Thanks

Comment: "has an existing collection that was created via Open Sea and is currently an ERC-1155 token" How did you realize it's an 1155 token? How we can get that info?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. NFTs aren't like wallet addresses which are unique globally. NFTs only make sense in the context of the contract that created them. Inside the contract, each token has an id that normally starts counting from 0.

So NFTs minted in a contract live forever in that contract.

Check https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).